# Search Results/Content Search Web part output in a list view

Tags: search-results, content-search-web-part, content

Is there a way to display more columns from a search results or content search web part and then those columns in  a list view? How can it be done?

Basically i would like to display search results (tasks assigned to a user) across all sites in a list view format which gives the ability to sort through different fields. Is there a way to implement it with OOB features in SharePoint 2013?

Thanks

Comment: You will have to (learn how to) develop your own [DisplayTemplates](https://www.google.nl/search?q=displaytemplates&tbs=qdr:y&tbo=1&as_oq=sharepoint&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=i2EeVpS5IYbtaLeintAL)